# How to insert an array into a mongodb collection as a separate document using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, mongodb, insertion

I am new to mongoDB. Now I am having some trouble inserting an array into a mongoDB collection. I want it to save as separate documents. For example I have an array like the following one:

```
 $aa = Array
 (
     [0] => Array
     ( 
        [id] => 1
        [name] => AA, BB & CC
        [colour] => 2
     )

     [1] => Array
     (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => DD
        [colour] => 3
     )
)
```

Now I want to insert/update/push it into a collection let's say called Test and I want to save it as individual document for each of them. I am using Alex Bilbie's library with my codeigniter.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was a very simple solution.

MongoCollection::batchInsert ( array $a [, array $options = array() ] )

this solved my issue.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php